# Change nuget.config location using environment variable in dotnet tool restore

Tags: c#, nuget, github-actions, dotnet-restore

I have a Github action that is running `dotnet tool restore` on my repo however I'm not able to modify this command and pass in the [-configFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore) parameter. Is there a way I can supply an absolute path to my custom nuget.config file via an environment variable?

I tried setting the `NUGET_RESTORE_MSBUILD_ARGS` environment variable hoping NuGet would pick it up but that hasn't worked.

I tried adding it to my github action directly:

```
name: My github action
on: pull_request
env:
  NUGET_RESTORE_MSBUILD_ARGS: /p:RestoreConfigFile=/home/runner/work/MyProj/CustomFolder/nuget.config
jobs:
  ...
```

As well as setting its value dynamically within the action using:

```
- run: echo "NUGET_RESTORE_MSBUILD_ARGS=/p:RestoreConfigFile=/home/runner/work/MyProj/CustomFolder/nuget.config" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```